# Data fetched from firestore database automatically changes order and get modified while scrolling the recycler view

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, chat, messaging

I have been trying to create a chat application and have implemented it using firestore database. The chat functionality works fine but as soon as the screen is filled and some scrolling is required to see the previous messages, the database updates in a weird way and the order becomes random and sometimes recent messages show up and sometimes older messages show up as a new message. I have used timestamp to order them but it doesn't seem to work. Even after using pagination, it didn't help. The data and order seem to change while scrolling the recycler view. I will put up the code and some screen shots for a better understanding.

**Message Model.java**

```
 public class MessageModel {
    String message, senderID, receiverID;
    Long timestamp;


    public MessageModel() {
    }

    public MessageModel(String senderID, String receiverID, String message, Long timestamp) {
        this.senderID = senderID;
        this.receiverID = receiverID;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public MessageModel(String senderID, String message) {
        this.senderID = senderID;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getReceiverID() {
        return receiverID;
    }

    public void setReceiverID(String receiverID) {
        this.receiverID = receiverID;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getSenderID() {
        return senderID;
    }

    public void setSenderID(String senderID) {
        this.senderID = senderID;
    }
}
```

**Message Adapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.chatdemo.Models.MessageModel;
import com.example.chatdemo.databinding.ReceiverTextItemBinding;
import com.example.chatdemo.databinding.SenderTextItemBinding;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class NewMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ReceiverTextItemBinding receiverTextItemBinding;
    private SenderTextItemBinding senderTextItemBinding;

    private Context context;
    private FirebaseUser fUser;

    private int SENDER_VIEW_TYPE = 1, RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE = 2;

    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy KK:mm a", Locale.US);

    private List<MessageModel> mMessage;


    public NewMessageAdapter(Context context, List<MessageModel> mMessage) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mMessage = mMessage;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == SENDER_VIEW_TYPE) {
            senderTextItemBinding = SenderTextItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
            return new SenderViewHolder(senderTextItemBinding.getRoot());
        } else {
            receiverTextItemBinding = ReceiverTextItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
            return new ReceiverViewHolder(receiverTextItemBinding.getRoot());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageModel messageModel = mMessage.get(position);

        if (holder.getClass() == SenderViewHolder.class) {
            senderTextItemBinding.tvSenderText.setText(messageModel.getMessage());
            senderTextItemBinding.tvSenderTextTime.setText(simpleDateFormat
                    .format(new Date(Long.parseLong(messageModel.getTimestamp().toString()))));
        } else {
            receiverTextItemBinding.tvReceiverText.setText(messageModel.getMessage());
            receiverTextItemBinding.tvReceiverTextTime.setText(simpleDateFormat
                    .format(new Date(Long.parseLong(messageModel.getTimestamp().toString()))));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (mMessage.get(position).getSenderID().equals(fUser.getUid())) {
            return SENDER_VIEW_TYPE;
        } else {
            return RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
    }

    public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView receivedMessage, receivedTime;

        public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            receivedMessage = receiverTextItemBinding.tvReceiverText;
            receivedTime = receiverTextItemBinding.tvReceiverTextTime;
        }
    }

    public class SenderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView sentMessage, sentTime;

        public SenderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            sentMessage = senderTextItemBinding.tvSenderText;
            sentTime = senderTextItemBinding.tvSenderTextTime;
        }
    }
}
```

**Chat Activity**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.chatdemo.Adapters.ChatAdapter;
import com.example.chatdemo.Adapters.NewMessageAdapter;
import com.example.chatdemo.Constants.Constants;
import com.example.chatdemo.Models.MessageModel;
import com.example.chatdemo.databinding.ActivityChatDetailBinding;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class ChatDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityChatDetailBinding binding;

    private Constants constants;
    private MessageModel messageModel;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestoreDB;
    private String userID;
    private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MessageModel> options;
    private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;

    public static final String TAG = "paginate";

    private NewMessageAdapter newMessageAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<MessageModel> mMessage;

    private final int limit = 15;
    private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;

    private boolean isScrolling = false;
    private boolean isLastItemReached = false;

    private String senderID, receiverID, receiverName, receiverPhoto;
    private CollectionReference collectionReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChatDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = firebaseAuth.getUid();

        constants = new Constants();

        senderID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
        receiverID = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiverID");
        receiverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiverName");
        receiverPhoto = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiverPhoto");

        binding.chatUserName.setText(receiverName);

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(Uri.parse(receiverPhoto))
                .into(binding.chatUserImage);


        binding.btnChatBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Go back
                startActivity(new Intent(ChatDetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        collectionReference = firestoreDB.collection(constants.getChats())
                .document(userID)
                .collection(constants.getMessages())
                .document(receiverID)
                .collection(constants.getMessages());


        binding.btnSendChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!binding.etMessage.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    String message = binding.etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                    messageModel = new MessageModel(senderID, receiverID, message, new Date().getTime());

                    binding.etMessage.setText("");

                    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatDetailActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Sending...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    firestoreDB.collection(constants.getChats())
                            .document(userID)
                            .collection(constants.getMessages())
                            .document(receiverID)
                            .collection(constants.getMessages())
                            .add(messageModel)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    firestoreDB.collection(constants.getChats())
                                            .document(receiverID)
                                            .collection(constants.getMessages())
                                            .document(userID)
                                            .collection(constants.getMessages())
                                            .add(messageModel)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(ChatDetailActivity.this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });


        collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatDetailActivity.this, "Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                readMessage(userID, receiverID);
            }
        });

        initNewRecycler();
    }

    private void initNewRecycler() {
        recyclerView = binding.chatRecyclerView;
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    }

    private void readMessage(String userID, String receiverID) {
        mMessage = new ArrayList<>();


        collectionReference.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(limit)
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                mMessage.clear();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    MessageModel model = snapshot.toObject(MessageModel.class);
                    if (model.getReceiverID().equals(userID) && model.getSenderID().equals(receiverID)
                            || model.getReceiverID().equals(receiverID) && model.getSenderID().equals(userID)) {
                        mMessage.add(model);
                    }

                    newMessageAdapter = new NewMessageAdapter(ChatDetailActivity.this, mMessage);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(newMessageAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Firebase firestore database structure**

```
   Firebase-root
   |
   ---- chats
           |
           ---- userID
                   |
                   ---messages
                         |
                         ---receiverID
                                |
                                ---messages
                                     |
                                     ---- message: "Hello!"
                                     |
                                     ---- timestamp: 1498472455940
                                     |
                                     ---- senderID: senderID
                                     |
                                     ---- receiverID: receiverID
```

**Some sample screenshots of the problem I have been facing**

*The first screen is what appears when the chat activity is first opened and the messages are displayed. Here everything works fine and the messaging system works.*
[image]

*In the second picture however we can see that when the user scrolls up to see the previous messages, some of them are shown correctly but some of them like "Does it work" and "No perhaps" have different time and some are not in the correct order. This happens frequently whenever the user scrolls the list*

[image]

This is the problem I have been facing for quite a while now. I am not sure what is causing this kind of behaviour and would love to have some light shed in this issue. If anyone can help, it would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo database structure added

Comment: That schema doesn't look like a Firestore schema, isn't it?